# Should I bring US passport to Lebanon for 2 week travel

Tags: us-citizens, canadian-citizens, lebanon

I have both a Canadian, and US passport. I am travelling to Lebanon (Beirut, but visiting some other places) in August. I plan on entering using my Canadian passport, but is there a good reason to bring along my US one as well?

At the moment it seems to me not worth bringing as 1) one more thing to lose 2) Americans are not viewed as friendly as Canadians. That said, are there situations where it would be difficult for the american embassy to help me for example if I do not have my US passport with me

Comment: When your trip ends, will you return to the US or to Canada?

Comment: I will in fact be returning to the UK where I study, so all is equal there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canadian passport only is best.

> 1. one more thing to lose

Exactly. Replacing a lost or stolen passport is expensive and time consuming.

> are there situations where it would be difficult for the american embassy to help me for example if I do not have my US passport with me ?

No. People show up at an embassy without a passport all the time. In fact, one the more frequent services of the embassy is to deal with lost or stolen passport. They may want to verify that you are a US citizen, but a simple photo of your passport should do the trick.

It's also not clear that the America embassy could do something that the Canadian couldn't.

I also have two passport and only take one wherever possible. In 100s of trips to  40+ countries I never had to deal with an unexpected event that required consulate or embassy assistance. These things are quite rare.

Comment: Counter argument, if you lose one passport, you can use the other to get home, but only if you have it with you.

Comment: @Willeke: there is good chance that if you lose one passport, you lose both. That would only work if you are careful to keep both passports always separate and in VERY different places. I personally don't do that since I have one way to keep them safe and trying to figure out a second way feels more risk than it adds redundancy.